# How to use proxy class and template to "simulate" function overload by return value?

Tags: c++, templates, types, return, overloading

I'll trying to dig into more c++ template and type system knowledge, I know that by overloading Type.Operator(), it will seem to "overload" by return type,

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class My{
    int getInt() const {return 20;}
    short getShort() const {return 3;}
public:
    template<class T>
    T get() const

    template<int>
    int get() const {return getInt();}

    template<short>
    short get() const {return getShort();}
};
struct Proxy{
    My const* myOwner;
    Proxy(My const* owner):myOwner(owner){}
    operator int() const {return myOwner->getInt();}
    operator short() const {return myOwner->getShort();}
};
int main(){
    My m;
    Proxy p(&m);
    int _i = p;//works!
    short _s = p;//works!
    cout<<_i<<","<<_s<<",\n";

    // How to use template My::get
    int i = m.get(); // doesn't compile
    short s = m.get(); // doesn't compile
    cout<<i<<","<<s<<",\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I expect there should be some way to make the following lines work to differ function call according to return type:

```
int i = m.get();
short s = m.get();
```

How to implement this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. `operator int() const {...}` is a user defined conversion and not a normal function. The return type is ignored during overload resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your goal, what's missing in your implementation (among other necessary fixes) is member function of `My` which actually returns a `Proxy`.

Something like the following (testable [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KkfRYfRkhh26eSUE))

```
#include<iostream>

class Proxy;

class My
{
public:
    template<class T = Proxy>  // <--
    T get() const;
};

class Proxy
{
    My const& owner_;
public:
    Proxy(My const& owner) : owner_(owner)
    {}
    operator int() const;
    operator short() const;
};

template<>
Proxy My::get<Proxy>() const {
    return *this;              // <--- 
}

template<>
int My::get<int>() const {
    return 20;
}

template<>
short My::get<short>() const {
    return -3;
}

Proxy::operator int() const {
    return owner_.get<int>();
}
Proxy::operator short() const {
    return owner_.get<short>();
}

int main()
{
    My m;
    int i = m.get<int>();
    short s = m.get<short>();
    std::cout << i << ", " << s << '\n';

    int i_ = m.get();
    short s_ = m.get();
    std::cout << i_ << ", " << s_ << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bob, I should say this is one of the best C++ template thread I've ever read, learning it again! My::get function of creates a Proxy out of My object itself, through its get function, and this Proxy converts into int/short by operation(), briliant!

Answer (score 3):

> ... to "simulate" function overload by return value?

Ignoring all the boilerplate of your example and focusing solely on this question, you could define a primary template function *with a deleted (primary template) definition*, and add explicit (full) specializations of this function only for the types for which you want to have an "overload":

```
#include <cstdint>

template <typename T>
T get() = delete;

template<>
uint8_t get<uint8_t>() { return 42U; }  // or delegate to getUint8().

template<>
uint32_t get<uint32_t>() { return 43U; }

template<>
float get<float>() { return 44.5F; }

int main() {
    const auto a = get<uint8_t>();
    const auto b = get<uint32_t>();
    const auto c = get<float>();
    // const auto d = get<uint16_t>(); // error: use of deleted function
}
```

Note however that you need to explicitly specify the type of the single type template parameter, as there is no argument of `get()` for template argument deduction to work with.

Comment: Thanks it's good code, but my question was focused on class member function that could work that the caller doesn't have to specify template type parameter, as it compiler could directly deduct it.

Comment: @Troskyvs it seems as if you want template type deduction based solely on the return type. This is not possible, as the return type does not take part in type deduction. You could always use other techniques such as tag dispatch or SFINAE to implement similar functionality as above, but in the end *some* call site needs to specify the type explicitly, as it cannot be deduced from the (non-existing) arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SFINAE like:

```cpp
template <typename T,
          typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, int>::value>::type* = nullptr>
int get() const {
    return getInt();
}

template <typename T,
          typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, short>::value>::type* = nullptr>
short get() const {
    return getShort();
}
```

Then in `Proxy` class call the above functions like:

```cpp
operator int() const {
    return myOwner->get<int>();
}
operator short() const {
    return myOwner->get<short>();
}
```

and in main function:

```cpp
int i = m.get<int>();
short s = m.get<short>();
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEJIAcpLegAyeWpgByxgEaZiIbpNIAHVAsJ1Wj1DEzNLPwC1OjsHZyM3Dy9FZUxVIIYCZmICEONTCxSVaNpM7IJYp1d3T28FLJy8sML68sr4xNqASkVUA2JkDgByKQBme2RDLHFRnXV64kxmIxnscQAGAEEDANEAalplzAUfZkG9%2BvQZ2S2NzcnmBQU9gFkAT3EAdhvNvb%2B9%2BwEPbATAEACS9AgXT2aFo9T2X2kiwI/Voe0k62uXwAInd/hcECQgSDGISclCYXR4Yjkai9qMsZ9cVsfAYXKw8MgQHj/gRMEYfMI%2BQjZgQ3j4tEc9gAVUg8/EKvZiiWHIyYC4EdAgECS9mYAD6eCoMx0l21eAU%2BoURxNsoB9FW2oAbmwDJhHSBlZgAFQi7EHAysVg%2BAjEVby%2B3E0EU2HU74R/G04hokkQghQrFbfE4u4RvkCoXqk1e1Xq2UJxVK8WStUarU6w56w3G2ZmkAWq022Z2hRkggel2Gd2jbDar2%2Bmb%2B2iB4Oh8NZ/69onA6PQ2NAxEVv5JlOghh9jOjH7Zpm509H3NbBYGVR7AAKxFQAA8PvGF393pS4QRfUY3gB5AB3Bwwwvd970fF8IE/ddfVQYD3C6EA/yAkCIHgkCuk3U9wNQCViGYIhiEjGMqQ3N9fkrHc9hQhDiAAWlWEkTUBVZD2Pf4c1w/DCJIAkiVI78EQoys9mo2iQMYkdmNbPs2KwsDKL%2BLjNhzRS7kBGjmHsDMRP%2BT8VkU/EH2fN49h8CApAANiMBSOL%2BTTDT9czrgAelcwCSAAawUMAwAjJccj2K1nJ8NyPO83z/PAtADH7WYTUNE1kskbwpEkZLZitTKdHSuUAFYdFodLM1U8D3L2AAJeClVQPYdnVfNBUI9V3m1ZjwM0vBnKMAA6GS5gdEd2ICvsLh6/rQRNQL4uwEaYr6eLctmPAcrykqEtbNbUoKoqNvssTQTpTF1KZIYelYEAhnyoZSFMIZ1lu1ArtymQ5AuPoBiLSRRk4W6CCux6uh6LyQHyyReqs0ZPnWT58s%2BThzHWTh8qstGhCu7hbvux7SGeoZboUEB1lIAGHvO0g4FgGBEBQVABTwdgyAoCA0AZpmQGAABObwqEZvliCJiAXEB26XHsbI3iuv7SDZtV6H/WhWCl8nSCwIwRGAdhRbVvBFnSJ1jh1zAnzSOLhlxwFlB1jkXAI4g3j0LBpf%2B4g8CMF2ehoegmDYDgeH4QRhFEFA5DkIQ8BcInIB6PCSiJoZ6Poy5JwkN6ZE4T5CdSdINAgawmlMTgrG0dpqg8YvIkCOhC8EKuSjLhIamLpRigyBpcn0fJBFbtISjKHJG86FuO9rke2nsKom4rnoFE%2BwYuAuq6brunX8afcwrPoqzuGBZBkD2LneskPYIFwQg%2BLGYu9j0dn3ARH7OGhV7ZBkf7ReB0hQeh3r8oxoYsakA9vlEmOMnpXUJsTUmH9KY0wgEgRarICDkEoGzHwjNm5WHwERQQ3tGAsG1pwbwgECI%2BE9v/FeYC8ZXSvnsQChAEB7A3lvHee8D5H0kO/cmn8EBLCwB4KE/9AHANAWvCBigoFkyBiDTwnxeqjCspIHmXhzCcC5uYbgoxRi8EukMUY2MxEE2gdwpeQxOGr1VvjLh0jSCG0FkETwQA%3D%3D%3D)

**NOTE**: The fact that the function return value is being assigned to an `int` or `short` isn't used in template parameter deduction.

Comment: Thanks works, but still one step from perfect, when we call template function, usually we don't specify the template type, as compiler could deduce it, so is there a way that we can "int i = m.get();", which compiler will call get<int> because of "int i"?

Comment: @Troskyvs that can't be done because the fact that it is being assigned to an int isn't used in template parameter deduction